# How to delete related record in Yii 2?

Tags: php, database, activerecord, model, yii2

I have a table (user) that has related data in another table (order) and the connection between them is one to many.

At [this example](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#saving-relations) I see how to create a related data (order). But how can I delete this data (order) when going over the user?

```
$customer = Customer::findOne(123);
$order = new Order();
$order->subtotal = 100;

// setting the attribute that defines the "customer" relation in Order
$order->customer_id = $customer->id;
$order->save();
$order->id; //e.g. 1
```

And my approach to delete it would be:

```
$order = $customer->getOrders()
    ->where(['=', 'id', 1])
    ->all();
$order->delete();
```

Is this the correct way?

**Note:** I use constraints.

Comment: You could handle this in your database constraints

Comment: Yes, it's handled in my database constraints. I'm just asking if this approach is the correct one.

Comment: It's definitely not incorrect but is simply unnecessary since you have your constraint already set up.  If you have some other processing you want to do (e.g. log that the particular user's orders were deleted), you can handle that in the method that @shivani mentions.

Comment: @kst hmm but I do not want delete the user, I just want delete this order. Maybe my example is bad.

Comment: @Jurik I see.  Then I think your approach is fine.  Just make sure you don't hard code that `1` in the `where` method (i.e. `->where(['=', 'customer_id', $cutomer->id])`).

Comment: Good and yes, it is not hardcoded. Ty

Answer (score 3):

you can use `beforeDelete` or `AfterDelete()` for delete related Table Data

Simple Example :

```
public function beforeDelete(){
    foreach($this->location_children as $c)
        $c->delete();
    return parent::beforeDelete();
}
```

Comment: I thought in a relational database and used constraints + Yiis active records you do not need such actions?

Comment: Yes Using constraints on Database side you can achieve your  goal,and in future you got a method to delete related data.